# Copying container with jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone, each

I've got three divs with the same class and each div has its own ID. I want to copy three other divs into these, based on their matching attributes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div").each(function(index, obj) {
    var matchingId = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    var matchingContainer = ("prod-cat-thumb-item-") + matchingId;

    if (matchingId == $(".prod-cat-item").attr("data-itemid")) {
      $(this).clone().prop("id", $(this).attr("id") + '-' + matchingId).prop("class", "thumb-gallery").appendTo($('.prod-cat-item[id="' + matchingContainer + '"]'));
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prod-cat-thumb-item-5" class="prod-cat-item" data-itemid="5">
  <p>Div Content</p>
</div>

<div id="prod-cat-thumb-item-6" class="prod-cat-item" data-itemid="6">
  <p>Div Content</p>
</div>
<div id="prod-cat-thumb-item-4" class="prod-cat-item" data-itemid="4">
  <p>Div Content</p>
</div>



<div id="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-4" class="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div">
  <div class="content">Other Content</div>
</div>

<div id="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-5" class="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div">
  <div class="content">Other Content</div>
</div>

<div id="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-6" class="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div">
  <div class="content">Other Content</div>
</div>
```

I'm stuck and help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate `prod-cat-item` and append targeted elements to it.

```
$(".prod-cat-item").each(function(index, obj) {
    //Get item Id
    var matchingId = $(this).data("itemid");    

    //Create selector to target element
    var matchingContainer = "#prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-" + matchingId;
    $(matchingContainer).addClass("thumb-gallery").appendTo($(this));
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".prod-cat-item").each(function(index, obj) {
    var matchingId = $(this).data("itemid");    
    var matchingContainer = "#prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-" + matchingId;
    $(matchingContainer).addClass("thumb-gallery").appendTo($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prod-cat-thumb-item-5" class="prod-cat-item" data-itemid="5">
  <p>Div Content</p>
</div>
<div id="prod-cat-thumb-item-6" class="prod-cat-item" data-itemid="6">
  <p>Div Content</p>
</div>
<div id="prod-cat-thumb-item-4" class="prod-cat-item" data-itemid="4">
  <p>Div Content</p>
</div>


<div id="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-4" class="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div">
  <div class="content">Other Content</div>
</div>

<div id="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-5" class="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div">
  <div class="content">Other Content</div>
</div>

<div id="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-6" class="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div">
  <div class="content">Other Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line `if(matchingId == $(".prod-cat-item").attr("data-itemid"))` is the problem, since `$(".prod-cat-item").attr("data-itemid")` always returnes the `data-itemid` of the first element. You can select the element having the same `data-itemid` using  `$(".prod-cat-item[data-itemid="+matchingId+"]")` so a sollution would be something like this, check it out:

```js
  $(".prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div").each(function(index, obj){
    var matchingId = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    var target =  $(".prod-cat-item[data-itemid="+matchingId+"]");
    $(this).clone().prop("id", $(this).attr("id") + '-' + matchingId).prop("class", "thumb-gallery").appendTo(target);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prod-cat-thumb-item-5" class="prod-cat-item" data-itemid="5">
    <p>Div Content</p>
</div>
<div id="prod-cat-thumb-item-6" class="prod-cat-item" data-itemid="6">
    <p>Div Content</p>
</div>
<div id="prod-cat-thumb-item-4" class="prod-cat-item" data-itemid="4">
    <p>Div Content</p>
</div>

<div id="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-4" class="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div">
  <div class="content">Other Content</div>
</div>
<div id="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-5" class="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div">
  <div class="content">Other Content</div>
</div>
<div id="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div-6" class="prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div">
  <div class="content">Other Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kep it very simple.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prod-cat-addt-details-thumbs-div").each(function(){
        var c = $(this).attr("id")[$(this).attr("id").length -1];
        $('#prod-cat-thumb-item-'+c).append($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Because I'm a beginner I can't really tell you why but the suggested answer from Satpal work better for my problem.